# not finding controller as per url in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a url as follows

```
http://localhost/realestate1/admin/users/login_form
```

i am not able to find admin controller in controllers . where else the controller wil be defined.

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your routing file, there might be prefix routing available for admin.
You may find it inside Admin folder in your controllers folder.